# Join in Spark returns duplicates implicit data types don't match

Tags: apache-spark, join, types

I am getting duplicates when joining on two dataframes where one key is a decimal and the other is a string.  It seems that Spark is converting the decimal to a string which results in a scientific notation expression, but then shows the original result in decimal form just fine.  I found a workaround by converting to string directly, but this seems dangerous as duplicates are created without warning. 
 Is this a bug?  How can I detect when this is happening?

Here's an demo in pyspark on Spark 2.4:

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('a', 9223372034559809871), ('b', 9223372034559809771)], ['group', 'id_int'])
>>> df1=df1.withColumn('id',col('id_int').cast(DecimalType(38,0)))
>>>
>>> df1.show()
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
|group|             id_int|                 id|
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
|    a|9223372034559809871|9223372034559809871|
|    b|9223372034559809771|9223372034559809771|
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+

>>>
>>> df2= spark.createDataFrame([(1, '9223372034559809871'), (2, '9223372034559809771')], ['value', 'id'])
>>> df2.show()
+-----+-------------------+
|value|                 id|
+-----+-------------------+
|    1|9223372034559809871|
|    2|9223372034559809771|
+-----+-------------------+

>>>
>>> df1.join(df2, ["id"]).show()
+-------------------+-----+-------------------+-----+
|                 id|group|             id_int|value|
+-------------------+-----+-------------------+-----+
|9223372034559809871|    a|9223372034559809871|    1|
|9223372034559809871|    a|9223372034559809871|    2|
|9223372034559809771|    b|9223372034559809771|    1|
|9223372034559809771|    b|9223372034559809771|    2|
+-------------------+-----+-------------------+-----+

>>> df1.dtypes
[('group', 'string'), ('id_int', 'bigint'), ('id', 'decimal(38,0)')]
```

Comment: I doubt that this is a bug. To perform join, spark has to convert both columns to common type, which turns out to be string for bigint an decimal. The fact that this happens silently is not very funny, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It's happenning because of the values (very very large) in the joining keys:

I tweaked the values in the joining condition and it's giving me the proper results :

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
    
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('a', 9223372034559809871), ('b', 9123372034559809771)],
                            ['group', 'id_int'])

df1=df1.withColumn('id',col('id_int').cast(DecimalType(38,0)))

df2= spark.createDataFrame([(1, '9223372034559809871'), (2, '9123372034559809771')],
                           ['value', 'id'])

df1.join(df2, df1["id"]==df2["id"],"inner").show()
```

Comment: This doesn't replicate the example above.  Even using your join syntax, I'm still getting duplicates. The problem only occurs when there are two (or more) observations which are indistinguishable when converted to scientific notation.